# Do Rakshas have Brahmana Varna among them?

Tags: brahmins, rakshasa

Rakshas can have Kshatriya Varna in them . The proof of it is , **Ravana** was son of a Rakshasi woman , but he was still considered as Brahmin.
The mother of Ravana was Rakshasi-Kshatriya . This is why Ravana was considered as Brahmin (as **son of a Brahmin father and Kshatriya mother is Brahmin**).

I want to know can Rakshas have Brahmins among them ?

Shukracharya was guru of Rakshas but he was not Rakshas himself.

Comment: varna and jati are independent concepts. there are 4 varnas in all jatis like men, devas, asuras, gandharvas.. e.g. ashvini kumaras (deva doctors) are deva shudras. they were denied havis bhaga of yagna until chyanava maharishi altered the rule to allow them. similarly, ravana was a brahmin varna belonging to rakshas jati. indra is deva kshatriya. agni is deva brahmana (he is purohit) etc.

Answer (score 2):

The term Brahmin refers to the priestly class so it may not just be dependent on their birth as in the case of Ravan, but also the activities that they perform. According to the [**Brahmand Puran**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc362865.html#note-t-125935) there are seven types of Rakshasas and the descendants of Agastya and Vishwamitra are referred to as Brahma-rakshas:

> Aiḍaviḍa (i.e. Kubera), the descendent of Pulastya, who was Savyapiṅgala (? Tawny-coloured in the left side) became the king of all Yakṣas, all those Rākṣasas who were the descendants of Pulastya, and of **all those cruel Brahmarākṣasas belonging to the families of Agastya and Viśvāmitra who still carried on the study of the Vedas and who performed regularly penances and holy rites.**

> **The other three groups of Rākṣasas were the performers of Yajñas. They were Yātudhānas, Brahmadhānas and Vārtās. They were moving about during the day time and they were not nocturnal wanderers like other demons.** Their four groups are remembered by the wise (learned men).

So it seems there were some Rakshas tribes that followed the Vedic injunctions and possibly they would be considered Brahmins amongst the Rakshas tribes.

Comment: The story of Vishvamitras sons....

Comment: I think it refers to the incident when he asked them to accept Shunahshepa as their eldest brother and they refused hence he cursed them to become rakshasas.